# Compilation Error in ASP.NET mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

`<div class="dateAdded">Article submitted @article.DateAdded.ToRelativeDateStringUtc()</div>`

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'ToRelativeDateStringUtc' and no extension method 'ToRelativeDateStringUtc' accepting a first argument of type 'System.DateTime' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is where my error is occurring. I have a class that contains `ToRelativeDateStringUtc()` included in my program. Is this a MS class that I have to import? I do not see it listed anywhere in the `.net` reference list. I'm sure its something simple, does anyone have any ideas?

I have already added the folder to my webconfig that includes the class, which contains the method the program is "missing". So its not missing it... I just dont know what else to do from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you could try.

Firstly, you can try the `using` directive inside the view you use this in:

```
@using Your.Namespace.Where.Extension.Class.Is.Located
```

Secondly, the `web.config` you've added the namespace to is probably the global one. If this view is inside an Area.. try putting the namespace into the `web.config` that is inside that particular area.

The first one will work regardless.

Comment: That was the trick. Funny how I no longer care about why its not working in the web.config! Thanks for the help Simon.